# Thunderpants & Smartypants are they the same?

Tags: discussion, new-users

[User Thunderpants](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/17752/thunderpants) has one answer today. One question above (see screenshot) is [Smartypants](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/17754/smartypants) who has no activity (?).

My guess is that Smartypants answered a question and it was deleted by peer review. If that is so, should the question's activity log be reset?

On the other hand, seeing the similarity in names, could they be the same person? If so, should any action be taken?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers bump questions, and deleting the answers doesn't unbump them. This is [pretty much by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120326/unbump-a-question-if-the-answer-providing-the-bump-is-deleted). Summarizing the linked post, the idea is that if deleting the answer unbumped the post, it'd provide a way for people to post bad answers without any of us noticing. They could post a spammy/offensive answer, delete it (unbumping it), then wait til it's off the front page before undeleting. If you try to fix this by making undeletes bump, then people can undelete their own answers to bump questions.

That said, when I saw that meta.SO post, I did comment on it expressing my displeasure - this is still pretty annoying, especially to <10k users (who are by far the majority). I wonder if perhaps *mod* deletion could unbump questions, while leaving self-deletion alone.

With respect to your second question, if a person is actually gaming the system by creating new accounts, the system (or the moderators) will catch on eventually - we have tools for that. I think in this case it's just a coincidence, though. Their writing style wasn't the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer which addresses both issues. But, I'm not satisfied with the explanation of the meta.se discussion. The team could program a 'bump' when an answer is undeleted... as that's the last activity.

Comment: @BaffledCook That's what the last sentence addresses - you don't want people to be able to repeatedly delete and undelete in order to bump. That's why I suggested the difference between mod deletion and owner deletion.